# Don't want to use any tag(including the default div tag) in Ember.Collection View

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Title may sound stupid, consider the following code

**My Handlebars File**

```
<table id="main-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>Some Text</h1>
    </td>
    {{#collection myCollectionView}}
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>{{view.someProperty}}</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>    
    {{/collection}}
  </tr>
</table>
```

**My View File**

```
myCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: "myController.someArray",
  //someArray has say 4 elements
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend()
})
```

I want it to render the 4 tables inside the #main-table, it instead renders them outside the #main-table because it encloses my `itemViewClass` inside the default `div` tag. I can only change the `tagName` property but can't set it to nil I guess, any hack for this issue?

[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59JqD/)

**In response to the first answer**
The problem with {{each}} is that, I am using an EditableField as follows:

*(just to sound clear, editable field is the one which changes a div to textfield on double click & back to div tag on focus out, simple widget built using ember)*

**updated Handlebars file**

```
<table id="main-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>Some Text</h1>
    </td>
    {{#collection myCollectionView}}
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>{{view.myEditableField valueBinding="view.content"}}</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>    
    {{/collection}}
  </tr>
</table>
```

**updated view file**

```
myCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: "myController.someArray",
  //someArray has say 4 elements
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    alertFunc: function(){
      alert("content did change");
    }.observes('content')
  })
})
```

I want an observer to fire whenever the value in one of the editableField is changed, so that I can update my records in database. Can we accomplish this thing using {{each}} helper? also, arrayContentDidChange will only fire if the array length changes

Comment: could you post the code of the myEditableFieldView ? Perhaps you can replace it with a simple `<input {{bindAttr value="view.content"}}>

Comment: You could still access to children views/parent view, as in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsrWe/ .If its still not sufficient, maybe you'll have to use a `Ember.ContainerView`. But personally, I think your template is not really clean, `CollectionView` should more be used as a `<tbody>` or directly a `<table>`, for example.

Comment: @sly7_7: [jsFiddle for Editable Field](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsrWe/3/)

Comment: @louiscoquio : I want to have columns of tables, this is a vague example, I am using <thead> & Ofcourse the code for {{collection}} is in my <tbody> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there can't be Ember.View without "real presence" in the DOM, but you can use the `{{each}}` helper if you don't want to add a view that acts as a container (here a `Ember.CollectionView`).

Set `tagName` to `null` does not work, [see Ember.View source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1287).

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <table id="main-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>Some Text</h1>
    </td>
    {{#each App.content}}
      <td>
        <table><tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr></table>
      </td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
</table>
</script>​
```

Code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.content = [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "baz"}];
```

​
See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NY3s7/).

Comment: Fine louis, +1. Thank you for your time helping people :)

Comment: @louiscoquio: Thanks for the reply, but please see the updated question, sorry I did not add this detail before

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to do this in a Ember View

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: ''
});
```

Comment: also false works. But not null. I think this was added since the question was originally asked though.

Comment: `tagName: ''` causes errors in changing the routes. My view is not destroyed on route change. (ember 1.2)

Comment: In ember 1.9.1 - tagName: '' works but setting it to false does NOT.

Comment: Came here to say what @Nathan said ^^

Comment: Suggestion for `false` @MichaelJohnston does not work as of ember 1.13.5 (HTMLBars), rather it creates an HTML tag `<false>`. `tagName: ''` works for me.